# Deleting key pair in android

Tags: java, android, keystore, private-key, public-key

I have created the public/private key using the android keystore when enrolling users in my application:

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(
                    "RSA", "AndroidKeyStore");
KeyPair kp=kpg.generateKeyPair();
```

How can I delete this key pair when the user enrolls. i cant find any functions to do so. Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it say that the KeyPair object you get is stored anywhere?

Comment: Maybe that is the reason there is no way to delete it :) On the other hand, when you use the key to signup and it's not stored, what do you do with it? Shouldn't you store it so the user can authenticate? Encrypted data without key is worth as much as random bytes.

Comment: I will be sending across the public key, as far as the private key is concerned it should be getting stored in the android keystore along with the public key. The problem is that I am new to android so not really sure where this keystore resides, though I think it would be there where the java keystore is. Thanks for your inputs, guess I need to a little more research.

Comment: oh.. maybe I'm wrong http://www.androidauthority.com/use-android-keystore-store-passwords-sensitive-information-623779/ - in https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyStore.html#getInstance%28java.lang.String%29 are methods for stored keys and to delete them

Comment: thanks will go through this and get back